# Injective and Surjective Function (Mapping)

Tags: functions

I had a question about mapping, for example:
what do they mean by $R \times R \to R$? is that not just $R \to R$?

Comment: $\times$ is the Cartesian product.

Comment: What does that mean exactly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we write $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ we mean that $f$ takes pairs $(x,y)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. For example, consider the map $f(x,y) = x$ then $f:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So we can take any pair, such as (2,4) to 4 for example?

Comment: Yup, its just a indicator which tells you what space each entry comes from. By convention we write $\underbrace{\mathbb{R} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{R}}_{n \ \textrm{times}} = \mathbb{R}^n$ because writing it out all the time would be painful.